# PHP same code twice with different internals

Tags: php

I am looking for a way to add a piece of code two times in my class with different functionality. This non working piece of code shows what I mean:

```
<?php
trait mytrait
{
  public $vari;
  public function setvar($var)
  {
    $this->vari = $var;
  }

  public function getvar()
  {
    return $this->vari;
  }
}

class myclass
{
  use mytrait;
  use mytrait
  {
    setvar as setvartwo;
    getvar as getvartwo;
  }
}

$x = new myclass();
$x->setvar("hello");
$x->setvartwo("world");
echo $x->getvar();
echo $x->getvartwo();
```

Expected result would be helloworld. The trait is also used in other classes but only once. I am looking for a nice solution to reuse the code in the trait twice. Any ideas? (also if you think it would be a good idea to make the trait a class or so, I am fine with a solution like that).

Comment: I don't think you understand how traits work. A trait is like a class method, well it is a class method actually, once used in that class. Why not add another function to the trait if you wish to have a `setvartwo`.

Comment: You want to be able to call the exact same method by two different names? What for exactly?

Comment: @Andrew, I understand that this does not work and that traits do not work this way. I am happy with any solution that is able to use my code twice in the same class.

Comment: @deceze, I want the exact same method twice, but I want it to use a different $this->vari. That way, I can use the same setvar() method for both vari's. (obviously my example is oversimplified). The only way I can think of is to have $vari as a parameter, but I considered that as ugly and hoped someone would come with a better method.

Comment: `public function setValue($key, $value) { $this->$key = $value; }` or you can hack it in with magic methods (`__call`) and test if the method starts with `set` or `get` and respons accordingly

Comment: You're not going to get what you're looking for using these semantics. Decorators as implemented in e.g. Python would be the right thing for the task, but that doesn't exist in PHP. Magic `__set__` is indeed pretty much your only choice here.